# Allow Adaptive Cells to Expand To Fill Height in GridView (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Problem**

I have a GridView, it has some cells with a fixed height, and some that are adaptive.. In a row where there are FixedHeight cells, I'd like the AdaptiveHeight cells to be tall as the tallest FixedHeight cell.

**Goal**

In this example, I'd like the black cells to be as tall as the red cell in row0, and the purple cell in row1.

[image: resulting gridview]

**Example**

Here is some reproducible code:

```
import SwiftUI

var farbe: [Color] = [
    .red, .orange, .yellow, .blue, .purple, .pink, .gray
]

struct Cell: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(color)
    }
}

struct GridTest: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.fixed(20), spacing: 20, alignment: .top),
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80, maximum: .infinity), alignment: .top),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            ForEach(1...9, id: \.self) { idx in
                if idx % 3 == 1 {
                    let color = farbe.randomElement()!
                    Cell(color: color)
                        .frame(height: CGFloat(idx) * 12)
                        .border(Color.black, width: 2)
                } else {
                    Cell(color: .black)
                        .border(Color(.systemGray6), width: 2)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color(.systemGray2))
    }
}

struct GridTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GridTest()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?